# (Theoretic) Convergence of integral

Tags: calculus

Prove or disprove:

Given $f(x)$ positive and continuous function in $[a,\infty]$ such that
$$\intop_a^\infty f(x)dx$$ converges, there exist $0<c<1$ such that 
$$\intop_a^\infty f^p(x)dx$$
converges for every $c\le p \le 1$.

**My try**:

By using the limit form of comparison test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {f(x)}{f^p(x)} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} {f^{1-p}(x)}
$$
because $f(x)$ is continuous
$$= \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)\right)^{1-p}$$

but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't necessarily exists.

Maybe this argument is false and there's a simple counter example?

Comment: A reasonably simple one.

Comment: Tried lots of function families. nothing works. any hint?

Comment: Let without loss of generality $a = 2$. You know that $$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\alpha} < \infty \iff \alpha > 1.$$ So $\frac{1}{x}$ sits right on the boundary, and you can look for a modification such that $\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\cdot g(x)} < \infty$, but $\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{(x\cdot g(x))^c} = \infty$ for all $c < 1$. So $g(x)$ should grow slower than any power of $x$, yet fast enough that $\frac{1}{x\cdot g(x)}$ is integrable.

Comment: You can simply cut the function off by defining $f(x) = \frac{1}{2(\log 2)^2}$ for $a \leqslant x \leqslant 2$. The critical thing is the behaviour at infinity, so you can choose a convenient point (e.g. $2$) and ignore what happens for smaller $x$.